# ¿Problema al multiplicar variables? en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

primero que nada tengo un problema al intentar multiplicar varios input, me funcionan si solo hago la operación con los id, pero una vez que intento usar variables que surgen problemas.
Lo mas extraño es que al principio me funcionaba y después dejaron de funcionar.

Esto es el código JavaScript donde hago la operación.

```
function calcular_total_ahorrado(){
try{
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("monto").value)|| 0,
    b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("plazo").value) || 0,
    c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Interes_pertenece").value) || 0;


    document.getElementById("total_ahorrado").value = a * b;
    document.getElementById("Interes_pertenece").value = (a * 100) / <?php echo $totalCuotaQuincenal; ?> * <?php echo $interesCantidadTotal; ?>  /100;
}catch(e) {}
```

}

estos son los input y select

```
<div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Interes que le pertenece en %') }}
        <input type="number" id="interes_pertenece" name="interes_pertenece" class="form-control">
        {!! $errors->first('Interes_pertenece', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Total Ahorrado + Interes') }}
        <input type="number" id="total_ahorrado_interes" name="total_ahorrado_interes" class="form-control">
        {!! $errors->first('total_ahorrado_interes', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('plazo') }}
    <select name="plazo" id="plazo" class="form-control" oninput="calcular_total_ahorrado()">
    {!! $errors->first('plazo', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
        <option>Seleccione el plazo de ahorro</option>
        <option oninput="calcular_total_ahorrado()" value="21">21 Quincenas</option>
          
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('total_ahorrado') }}
        {{ Form::number('total_ahorrado', $ahorro->total_ahorrado, ['class' => 'form-control id="total_ahorrado"' . ($errors->has('total_ahorrado') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Total Ahorrado']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('total_ahorrado', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('monto') }}
        {{ Form::number('monto', $ahorro->monto, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('monto') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Monto']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('monto', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
```

y este es el error que me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui esta en la linea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí declaro las variables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sinceramente tal vez sea algo sencillo pero ya no se que sucede, mas que nada por que me funciona, y derrepente después de un rato, me marca este error, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Puede que el problema radique en las funciones PHP `ObtenerInteresCantidadTotal();` y `ObtenerCuotaQuincenal();`
Estas dos funciones al parecer no están retornando nada, ya que al realizar el echo de estas variables en la formular JS, está quedando sin valores

Comment: No olvides colocar todo el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes. Por otra parte, ¿depuraste tu código? Puede que "después dejaron de funcionar" porque alguna de esas funciones en PHP retorna nulo en algún momento.

Comment: Es que si no ejecutas el php en un archivo php corriendo en un servidor php no va a funcionar. `<?php echo $totalCuotaQuincenal; ?> * <?php echo $interesCantidadTotal; ?>` Por eso no hay nada entre las dos "/" y por eso encuentra un error: "/ * /"

Comment: @MichaelSt.Avila Gracias, realmente ese era el problema, por equivocación mía, no me percate que no estaban retornando nada. la base de datos por alguna razón le di reset. y por esa misma razón me daba el problema